# Vapor 2.0: Where is the SQLite stored?

Tags: swift, sqlite, vapor

I'm using Vapor and a built-in SQLite 3 driver: https://github.com/vapor/sqlite

So i changed `"driver": "memory"` to `"driver": "sqlite"` in **fluent.json** and created **sqlite.json**:

```
{
    "path": "data.sqlite"
}
```

But even if I use Spotlight search I cannot find any file called data.sqlite. I cannot also use `sqlite-provider` which is popular in many tutorials I found because it's not compatible with Vapor 2:
**Could not generate Xcode project: swift-package: error: unsatisfiable**

But nevertheless the data is stored somewhere: I can reboot my Mac, run Vapor and see all the data.

I have read a lot of similar questions here but none of authors used Vapor, so those answers hasn't help me. I need to get this data.sqlite file location. What am I doing wrong?

**P.S** I'm using Xcode 8.3.2, Swift 3.1, Vapor 2.0.1. SQLite3 is installed.

Comment: One small comment in case others found this, SQLite is bundled by default in Fluent 2 as our in memory driver, so anywhere you see SQLiteProvider, assume you've already got it :)

Answer (score 3):

Well, I still don't understand where Vapor store database files, but I found this solution:

```
Xcode > Product > Scheme > Edit Scheme > Options >  Use Custom Working Directory
```

I set this to my project's parent directory and data.sqlite appears there.

However, I still wonder where and under what name they were originally stored if even Spotlight can't find them.

Comment: When Xcode builds, it does so in obscure build folders that sometimes spotlight doesn't pick up, you've probably got some data files stuffed in a weird xcode cache somewhere, glad you resolved it!

Comment: If you don't use a custom working directory it puts it in something like: 
 `/Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Project-dlznctnmjbjclzfvgfiarghfckgq/Build/Products/Debug/db.sqlite`

Comment: This assumes you are running from an Xcode project (which is not seen as a production thing).  If you run it using `vapor run` it puts in the current directory.

Comment: For who is still wondering how to do it: it's easier to just clear your derived data folder.

Answer (score 2):

A terminal `find` command line can be used to find the "data.sqlite" (or other known database name) file not otherwise locatable by Spotlight Search:

```sh
sudo find / -name "data.sqlite" -print
```

In the Vapor 2, SQLite is a part of `Fluent` so `SQLiteProvider` is no longer needed.  Tutorials which use `SQLiteProvider` would instead use `FluentProvider`.

For the Vapor 2 default `api` template, `Fluent` is included.  For the Vapor 2 non-default `web` template, `fluent-provider` needs to be added to `Package.swift` and subsequently configured in the code.

*For `swift package tools-version` 3.1.0*

```swift
dependencies: [
    …
    .Package(url: "https://github.com/vapor/fluent-provider.git", majorVersion: 1),
```

*For `swift package tools-version` 4.0.0*

```swift
dependencies: [
    …
    .package(url: "https://github.com/vapor/fluent-provider.git", .upToNextMajor(from: "1.3.0")),
```

My finding for where the SQLite file is generated for Vapor 2 follows...

```sh
vapor --version
# Vapor Toolbox: 2.0.3
# Vapor Framework: 2.1.0
```

```sh
vapor new VaporDefaultExample
cd VaporDefaultExample/Config
nano fluent.json # edit to: "driver": "sqlite" 
nano sqlite.json # create file. add { "path":"FindMeSQLite.sqlite" }
```

Note that the expected .sqlite location is specifed in the `Config/sqlite.json` file.

```sh
cd ..
vapor update
vapor build
vapor run &
sudo find / -name "FindMeSQLite.sqlite" -print
```

Result: "FindMeSQLite.sqlite" is found at path/to/VaporDefaultExample/FindMeSQLite.sqlite as specified in `Config/sqlite.json`

```sh
# ^C quit the previous vapor run
# then create Xcode project
vapor xcode -y
# run project in Xcode
# then, repeat the find
sudo find / -name "FindMeSQLite.sqlite" -print
```

Result: "FindMeSQLite.sqlite" is again found at `path/to/VaporDefaultExample/FindMeSQLite.sqlite` as specified in `Config/sqlite.json`

NOTE: if the .sqlite location is different for your configuration, then `find` on either macOS or Ubuntu should reveal such location.

Answer (score 0):

This happens when you use XCode to build and run your Vapor Project.
Xcode uses local temporary directory for every app which is in development stage.
Use Vapor's CLI in terminal

```
 $ vapor build 
 $ vapor run
```

Then all your old database will be deleted and a new .sqlite file is created in your main directory.